# How to remove auto sort and edit below code for number entry in query group function google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to run a query function in google sheet for every columns separately, but it automatically sort the output in alphabetically order as shown in below image which I don't want. Also, it is not working for number entry as in column H and I (might be due to IF NUMBER function). Please help me.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smnGL.png)

My function is(separate for every column) -

=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(QUERY({INDEX(QUERY(A2:B,
"select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), , 1),
REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(A2:B,
"select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0)), INDEX(QUERY({A2:A,B2:B&";"},
"select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 offset 1", 0), 1,), ))
, , 999^99))), ";$", )}, "offset 1", 0), , 1))

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
={A1:D1;
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(transpose({
transpose(unique(A2:A));
arrayformula(regexreplace(trim(query(arrayformula(if(A2:A=transpose(unique(A2:A)),B2:B&",",)),,9^9)),"[,\s]+$",""))
}),counta(unique(A2:A)),2),
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(transpose({
arrayformula(regexreplace(trim(query(arrayformula(if(A2:A=transpose(unique(A2:A)),C2:C&",",)),,9^9)),"[,\s]+$",""))
}),counta(unique(A2:A)),2),
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(transpose({
arrayformula(regexreplace(trim(query(arrayformula(if(A2:A=transpose(unique(A2:A)),D2:D&",",)),,9^9)),"[,\s]+$",""))
}),counta(unique(A2:A)),2)}
```

[image]